# How do I store the name of a input string for a different C file?

Tags: c, scope, function-declaration, function-parameter

What I am trying to do is ask the name of someone and then storing it so I can use it for different scripts. Here is what I have so far.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"
int main()
{
    printf("welcome to the dungeon crawler.\n");
    //ask for the name//
    printf("please state your name: ");
    char name[100];
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("hello %s.\n", name);
    main2();
    return 0;
}
```

**main2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"
int main2()
{
    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

**functions.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
int name;
#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

When I try to run it, main2 says (null).

Comment: After a script finishes running, all it's data get's thrown away. If you want to persist some information you would have to save it to a text file.

Comment: 1) "main2()" is a VERY poor choice in names.  "test_globals()" might be a better name. 2) "functions.h" declares a global "int".  Yet (badly-named) "main2()" is trying to print a string.  Hence the "null".  Whoops!  3) "functions.h" should probably declare `extern char *name;`.  4) Then "main()" defines it, populates it ... and "main2()" prints it.

Comment: in functions.h, name is declared as int, that should be char*, and main() should not overrides it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration in main

```
char name[100];
```

declares a local variable that is not alive outside main.

This declaration in `functions.h`

```
int name;
```

declares a global variable of the type `int` that is zero initialized.

You have two choices.

Either the function `main2` will have a parameter of the type `char *` or `const char *`

```
int main2( const char *name );
```

(Place the function declaration in the header `functions.h`)

and will be called like

```
main2( name );
```

Or remove the global variable

```
int name;
```

in the header `functions.h` and instead of it move the local declaration

```
char name[100];
```

from the module `main.c` in the header declaring it like

```
extern char name[100];
```

In one of the modules in the file scope you place the variable declaration for example like

```
char name[100];
```

On any case the declaration of the function `main2` must be placed in `functions.h`.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to run it, main2 says (null).

Because you did not pass any parameter to that function.

You should use some descriptive name rather than `main2`. There should be only one `main`, any other function should have descriptive name that describe what it does. For example:

```
void printit(const char * string)
{
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Then from your main, you need to pass the `name` to that function:

```
printit(name);
```

As a side note, you should initialise your char buffer, and make sure your `scanf` does not read more characters than it should:

```
char name[100] = "";    
scanf("%99s", name);
```